# How can I safely upload a large file from the browser to a bucket on Amazon S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser, upload

I need to allow a user to upload a large file (over 2GB) from the web application and I don't want to expose the company's access keys.

One of my teammates found that to upload without the keys we need to use presigned urls. In this way, the frontend requests a presigned url to the backend and, after receiving it, the frontend uploads the file via an HTTP request. Following is the code that does this:

```js
const presignedUrl = '...'

const body = {
    data: file,
};

const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', presignedUrl, body, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': contentType,
        'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
    }),
    reportProgress: true,
});
```

I found that to upload large files via the AWS Node SDK, we just need to set the options object that is passed as an argument to the upload method as follows:

```js
const options: AWS.S3.ManagedUpload.ManagedUploadOptions = {
    partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // each part is 10 MB
    queueSize: 2, // 2 parts are uploaded concurrently
};

const params: AWS.S3.PutObjectRequest = {
    Bucket: 'teste-multipart-upload',
    Key: key,
    Body: body,
};

return s3.upload(params, options, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

How can I do these two things at the same time? Either upload via SDK to a presigned url or upload a large file via the provided REST API (if there's another option I'd like to know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a series of steps:

1. The back-end initiates the multipart upload.
2. The back-end creates a series of pre-signed URLs, one per part, and sends them to the client.
3. The client uploads the various parts to those pre-signed part URLs (in any order).
4. The client tells the back-end that it's done, and the back-end completes the multipart upload.

See [Multipart uploads with S3 pre-signed URLs](https://www.altostra.com/blog/multipart-uploads-with-s3-presigned-url) for an example.

Comment: Thank you so much. Does this approach work if my backend is hosted as a Firebase Cloud Function? They have a short time to live, so I don't know if it's doable to keep a session or wait in any way for the frontend to end the upload.

Comment: You wouldn’t wait for the front end to complete the upload. This needs to be an API call that it makes to your backend when it’s completed the uploading. It’s an asynchronous process. There’s no reason this won’t work on any hosting platform as long as you have the ability to run the AWS SDK of your choice and you can provide AWS credentials to that environment.

Comment: Oh, I understand. The complete process is stateless, right? If for some reason the frontend never confirms the upload is complete, does S3 automatically discard the parts? On a side note, how did you manage to find this article? I did a lot of research and I didn't find anything close. Anyway, thanks again, it helped me a lot.

Comment: If a multipart upload completion doesn't happen then the uploaded parts are orphaned and remain. There is no timeout after which S3 clears up for you. It's your responsibility to [abort the multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/abort-mpu.html). How did I find that article? First search result at `https://www.google.com/search?q=s3+multipart+upload+signed+url`.

Comment: @jarmod, I checked your tutorial, don't you think it is problematic frontend code has sensitive info like `secretAccessKey` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72635343/how-to-upload-to-aws-s3-without-sharing-confidential-information

Comment: @János that would be very problematic, but that's not the intention here. Only the backend should have the AWS credentials and it initiates the multipart upload and generates pre-signed URLs, one per part. The backend shares the pre-signed URLs with the front-end. The front-end uploads the individual parts to the pre-signed URLs. The front-end never has AWS credentials. The example I pointed to perhaps isn't ideal because it doesn't clearly distinguish between frontend and backend, but it does provide code that's helpful for both, which is why I added it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it up so you handle it all in the browser safely with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html

And then you can use [S3.ManagedUpload()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html), which does all the work for you, instead of manually creating urls on the server.

(Note, this is TypeScript, but you can just remove " as HTMLInputElement" and change the import and if you want JS)

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

AWS.config.update({
  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId: "us-east-1:..."}),
  region: "us-east-1"
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

document.getElementById("file-input").addEventListener("change", event => {
  const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const file = inputElement.files[0];
  const params = {
    Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
    Key: file.name,
    Body: file
  }

  const upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({params});
  upload.send((err, data) => {
    console.log({err, data});
  });
}, false);
```