# How to upload to AWS S3 without sharing confidential information?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Checking this tutorial: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-upload-files-to-aws-s3-in-react-591e533d615e

Why they fill in frontend code confidential data like:

```js
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE',
    secretAccessKey: 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_HERE'
})
```

In our case backend presigned a URL, and client should only upload the file to that specific url. I would use this library, but I have doubt wether those data I can share publicly.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk#getting-help

So how to upload raw image to S3 programmatically?

---

Shall I have 2 S3 identity one for presigning and one for uploading the file? Presigning can be executed only from backend, after permission of the user was checked. Uploading anyone can do, but because fileName has a constrain, anyone can not upload anything to my bucket.

Comment: You should use presigned URL in your frontend

Comment: Why presign in the frontend? Why not in backend?

Comment: To be clear, you backend should sign the URL and send it to the frontend. The frontend uses the presigned URL to send request to the AWS service.

Comment: Once the client has the Presigned URL back from the server, simply `POST` the photo Blob to the Presigned URL using `fetch` or `axios` or whatever.